# Find all InfoPath Forms in SharePoint Online and when last used?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, infopath, pnp-powershell

I am new to this site and have a few questions that I will post. I have used this site quite a bit in the past for answers, but just recently joined and want to thank everyone for their contributions.

Now - I have a question that is very similar to a question already answered by the great Mike Smith. That can be [found here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240149/get-the-list-of-all-available-infopath-forms-in-a-sharepoint-site-collection-s/240180#240180):

I was not able to comment on that post as my reputation isn't strong enough just yet. What I am trying to find out is if that solution automatically creates an output file with appropriate columns, and also if there is a tag we can use to also get the last modified date.

The ultimate goal is to find all InfoPath forms, where they are located, and when/if they are even being used at all.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Joe