# SharePoint Online - Find all Infopath Forms in all sitecollection with csv?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, infopath, online

I am looking for some help here.

I have a need to find all infopath forms in a SharePoint online environment. I need to run through all site collections (alot of them) and write to csv file for review. I have noticed there is a powershell script here: [infopath script](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240149/get-the-list-of-all-available-infopath-forms-in-a-sharepoint-site-collection-s/255243) how ever when I run it it keeps prompting me for login details for the next site collection. I have so many site collections is there anyway to stop this and keep running the script until the end automatically?. Also is there a way to output this to a csv file for review???

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work to convert your user login to pass through the script. Also, you can look at saving your password to a file if you want to have better security around your script.

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "PlainTextPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd)
```

or to file...

```
read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\cred.txt
```

Once we have our password safely stored away, we can draw it back into our scripts..

```
$password = get-content C:\cred.txt | convertto-securestring
```

Then finally, we can create our credential object, which we pump into other cmdlets.

```
$credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "myusername",$password
```

Then you can loop through each site collection. Wrap the code from your previous link into a function (Get-Forms) and loop through each site collection. You can opt to run this on a weekly schedule and exported the results to a SharePoint file library that held these kind of csv files.

```
$SiteCollections = Get-SPSite 'https://<site name>' | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select Title
foreach($Sitecollection in $SiteCollections){
     Get-Forms -SiteCollection $SiteCollection
}
```

Comment: Another way is to take a stab at the content  types being used for each App. You can create and run a script to export this contents too. It would be helpful.